# Enforce C-style comments in visual studio 2005

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, comments, c89

In order to enforce **C89 code conformance**, I would like Visual Studio 2005 **not to accept C++-style comments** (`// my comment`), but only C-style comments (`/* my comment */`).

Is there any available configuration in Visual Studio 2005 for that purpose? Thanks.

Comment: May be relevant: http://www.tucuxi.org/c89-c99.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, sorry for that self-answered question. Everything is [there](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/049e298f-129d-4463-b2b7-4627e5a5c315).

Just in case the link becomes unavailable: you need to **enable strict mode** (`/Za`), and add either a pragma or a compiler option in order to activate warnings or errors on these comments:

- for a warning `#pragma warning(1:4001)` or `/w14001`
- for an error `#pragma warning(error:4001)` or `/we4001`

All the best